# Questions about Java's library map classes?

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap, maps, treemap

The answers are (2) and (4) but not sure why. I don't have much foundation on these topics. Could someone please explain why these are the correct answers and why the others are incorrect.
Thank you
[image]

Comment: these are questions which you can get answers both on StackOverflow and the world wide web.

Comment: 2 is trivial, [it says so in the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) : `Map: An object that maps keys to values. A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one value. `

Comment: a map is basically a list of key and value pairs. One restriction is that the key is unique, so it is distinguishable from other keys. It's sort of like a number plate on your car - it is unique in itself and is associated with a car (value). If the police want to lookup which arse was speeding again it can look up the number plate it saw and check the associated value

Comment: HashMap, LinkedHashMap and TreeMap are 3 different implementations of the Map design - from the outside they are all equally capable from what a Map should be able to do(basically getting a value, setting a value and removing a value).

Comment: It’s fine you ask without knowing why 2 and 4 are the correct answers, but at least tell us about the research you’ve done and what you do understand. Then it’s much easier to write an answer at the right level.

Answer (score 1):

A HashMap is a data structure that consists of keys and values. Values are stored in the HashMap with an associated key. The values can then be retrieved by recalling from the HashMap with the same key you used when putting the value in.

### 1

TreeMaps and LinkedHashMaps are different versions of a Map. A HashMap uses hashing to store its keys, whereas a TreeMap uses a binary search tree to store its keys and a LinkedHashMap uses a LinkedList to store keys. If you iterate over a HashMap, the keys will be returned in hash-sorted order (unpredictable in most cases), because that's how they were stored. The TreeMap, however, has a tree of all the values, so when you iterate over the tree, you'll get all the keys in actual sorted order. A LinkedHashMap has the keys in an ordered list, so an iterator will return the keys in the same order in which you inserted them.

### 2, 3, and 5

In a HashMap, values are looked up using their keys. If you had duplicate keys, the HashMap couldn't know which value to return. Therefore, every key in a HashMap must be unique, but the values do not have to be.

### 4

In a normal HashMap, the key is hashed and then inserted in the appropriate spot. With a TreeMap and a LinkedHashMap, you have the additional overhead of inserting the key into the tree or linked list which will take up additional time and memory.

Comment: Thorough explanation. And very nice explanation of why 2 is correct. It seems you are not distinguishing very clearly between map and hash map. Not all maps are hash maps. A tree map is *not* a specialized version of a hash map — it’s a different map implementation altogether.

Comment: Thanks -- updated to reflect the changes you suggested